# K-theory and homology of groups

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, group-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory

It is known that for any ring $R$, 
$$K_{1}(R)=H_{1}(GL_{\infty}(R), \mathbb{Z})$$ 
$$ K_{2}(R)= H_{2}(E_{\infty}(R),\mathbb{Z})$$
$$ K_{3}(R)= H_{3}(St_{\infty}(R),\mathbb{Z})$$
where $GL_{\infty}= lim GL_{n}$, $E_{\infty}=lim E_{n}$ (elementary matrices) ,  $St_{\infty}=lim St_{n}$ (Steinberg groups).

Question:

Is there a same description of higher groups of algebraic K-theory. i.e. for each $n>0$ there exist a group $M^{n}=lim M_{i}$ such that $$ K_{n}(R)= H_{n}(M^{n}(R),\mathbb{Z})$$ 
where every thing is functorial. 
in our case $M^{1}= GL_{\infty}$, $M^{2}=E_{\infty}$ and $M^{3}=St_{\infty}$.

Comment: At the least, there is a (perfect) group $M^n(R)$ which achieves this, but I'm not sure that it's a direct limit of nontrivial stuff. Quillen defines $K_n(R)$ as $\pi_n$ of $BGL(R)^+$, and we can find an $(n-1)$-connected cover $X_n\to BGL(R)^+$ which is an isomorphism on $\pi_n$, and now we can invoke the Kan-Thurston theorem to find $M^n(R)$ such that $\pi_n(BX_n^+)\cong\pi_n(BM^n(R)^+)\cong H_n(M^n(R))$.

Comment: Chris Gerig, this construction is functorial in R ?

Comment: I don't know (I should've clarified my phrase "achieves this" was referring to the homology statement alone).

Comment: Yes. The non-stable Volodin groups. See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0062181

Comment: @ChrisGerig If I understand the comments, it seems that you have answered the question. If this is correct, perhaps you can leave a (slightly expanded?) answer?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I don't think it's in the "direct limit" spirit of what the OP wanted, but if it is good enough then I can post it. From glancing at the paper linked by *user40276*, the Volodin groups may be what the OP wanted (but I didn't read it enough so I don't know if it gives the homology statement). By the way, my comment has erroneous notation: $BX_n^+$ should be just $X_n$.